# Referenced assembly 'GenCode128.dll' is not a valid assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, .net-assembly

I am now dealing with a existing solution in VS2012.

Now I can execute it in debug mode but cannot trigger some of the function with the error

> "Exceptions: System.Exception: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.Score, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5ce8a8a190705d24' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

After finding some of the suggestion, some of that suggest me to compile the solution in 32-bit (x86).

However, when I tried to rebuild with the target platform x86, another type of error occur and I even cannot run in debug mode, the error:

Referenced assembly 'GenCode128.dll' is not a valid assembly C#

P.S. GenCode128.dll is one of the error .dll, there is at least 2 of this kind of error.

I cannot search any successful way to solve this problem, appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decompiler such as DotPeek (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler) to look inside your DLL and see if it is a valid .NET DLL -- and which version of .NET it is. It could be an x64-compiled assembly; in that case you cannot use it on a 32-bit system or from a 32-bit-compiled .NET assembly.

Comment: I am not permitted to download program online. Before finding way to do that, I found that even I have not change anythings from the "Runable" version, when I going to rebuild it, these kind of error will also be occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it from NuGet.

I've created a NuGet package for `GenCode128.dll` here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GenCode128/

Also the source can be found in GitHub: https://github.com/SourceCodeBackup/GenCode128